# How would I design a row-key in Bigtable if I was designing an application that should search for tags/columns?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, architecture, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I'm trying to design a Netflix search like system, and I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around the concept on how to design an optimal rowkey that would minimize total table scans when the user executed a search by a column like the name of the show or tags.

Assuming the schema in BigTable would have columns like: showName, season, episode, episodeName, tags

How could I design my rowkey in such a way that if a user searched for a specific column it would avoid full table scans? Or would I need to change my database design?

Or do systems like Netflix use a different mechanism to perform searches on their content in a more optimal way?

Comment: Hi! Could you tell me more about what the tags mean?
Also, from the writing it seems that you want to be able to search by Season or Episode. Like the first episode of all series?

Answer (score 0):

I would go first for two tables:

1. Episode Table with key: showName#season#episode which indexes how to find episodes.
2. And a Tag Table for searching for tags with a simple key: tag which points to the key of the row in Episode Table.

For instance an episode or series with tag Terror and Drama would appear twice in the Tag Table, first under Drama and then under Terror.